# Android app to generate bugreport

Tags: android, privacy, bug-reporting

Occasionally users of our Android app is run into an obscure problem in the Google infrastructure that Google is trying to track down.  And naturally the Engineer working on it wants to see some bugreport output when this happens.  Which brings us down to the old problem of how do I get a non-techie end user to generated and send in a bugreport.  Installing the SDK, configuring for a Windows system so that can do an 
adb bugreport
doesn't sound feasible.

I've been looking around for a simple app that will do this, with no success.  So I tried adding that capability to my own app.  And this is where I need help.  If I use the shell command to access my device, I can generate reports with something simple as
sh -c 'bugreport | gzip > bugreport.gz'
But if I try to execute this from my app, bugreport just displays an error message
Failed to connect to dumpstate service
I'm guessing that I am missing some odd permission, but have no idea what it might be.

Anyone have any ideas what I can try?

Answer (score 3):

If I am not wrong, you want to see the error log when the application is crashed. For this you can integrate [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) library with the code. This can generate the runtime uncaught errors and that can be sent to email or specific server.

Answer (score 3):

The "shell" user has permission to do things that apps don't, so you can't simply run bugreport from an app.

On Android 4.2 and later you can take a bug report from the Developer Options menu.  The menu can be enabled by going into Settings, selecting About Phone, and tapping on Build Number seven times.  (This is documented [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html), under On-device Developer Options.)

The generated bug report can be sent through e-mail (watch for a notification to appear).  In some circumstances it's less useful than "adb bugreport" would be, since you have to switch to Settings to generate the report, but it will have the full logs and other goodies.  There's a magic key sequence that will initiate bugreports, but I don't know if there's a way to enable it on non-dev devices.

Answer (score 0):

Android now has the ability to capture a bug report at will. To quote from an [android issue comment by a project member](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216395#c1):

First enable bug report shortcuts:

> navigate to developer settings, ensure ‘USB debugging’ is enabled, then enable ‘Bug report shortcut’.

When you have run across a bug:

> To take bug report, hold the power button and select the ‘Take bug report’ option.

That will generate a zip archive and offer to share it, e.g. via email, upload to Google drive or whatever.  But note that the bugreport zip file contains a bunch of information that may be considered private, so users should only share it with folks they trust to use it appropriately. And of course also note that the developer of an app probably already can access some or all of that information. The [ChkBugReport](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/01/25/new-bugreport-analysis-tool-released-as-open-source/) tool gives insights into what is reported. But I haven't seen a good security/privacy writeup (or really any official documentation on all this) so I advise appropriate caution.